# Opening VS code in the matching CWD with 'code'?

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04

I recently saw that running `code` in the terminal would open VSC for me.

I then noticed, it doesn't open it within the CWD directory. Although clicking `FIle > Open Folder > Selecting the folder` isn't a huge pain, it would be nice for it to work dynamically.

I'm guessing I have to pass an argument? Altough I would like it to work dynamically rather than manual, I'm hoping someone can guide me to a way to do this with `.bashrc`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I have found success using `code .`.

Comment: This seems to open it in the home directory, or maybe its just me? I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: are you *in* the home directory?

Comment: Haha, forgot I went to the home to edit my `.bashrc`, sorry man.

Answer (score 0):

Running `code $PWD` seemed to do it for me. Still too much? I managed to get it working without having to pass `$PWD` with it, just add an alias to `.bashrc`.

Open the .bashrc file,

`nano .bashrc`
`

Scroll to the bottom & add:

`alias code='code $PWD'`

Thanks.